# ExecTask is not running

Tags: php, xml, shell, exec, phing

I have the following `build.xml` file:

```
<project name="myProject" default="testTarget" basedir=".">
    <target name="testTarget">    
        <echo msg="starting task..." /> 
        <exec command="echo hiiiiii" />
        <echo msg="finished task..." /> 
    </target>        
</project>
```

when I run the target from the command line `phing testTarget` the following is shown of the terminal:

```
Buildfile: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/myProject/build.xml

myProject > testTarget:

     [echo] starting task...
     [echo] finished task...

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.1346 seconds
```

As you see the `<exec command="echo hiiiiii" />` isn't running!!

I'm using Phing 2.6.1 and PHP 5.3.24 with Xdebug v2.2.3

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding `passthru="true"` made it work. So the new task should be:

```
<exec command="echo hiiiiii" passthru="true" />
```